# Stack Overflow Data Explorer real unanswered questions count

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm trying to query the great Data Explorer tool to ask all kinds of questions about unanswered questions on Stack Overflow.

The problem is that there's a vast inconsistency between the results I get in my queries and the results that Stack Overflow publishes on the main site.

Specifically, Stack Overflow declares that there are

> **651,080** questions with no answers

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers))

However when I run this simple query which should give me the same result on Stack Overflow's DB -

> select count(*) from posts where posttypeid = 1 and answercount = 0

I get this result -

> 56873

Unless I've written the wrong query for what I would like to know, this number is far off what Stack Overflow's officially declare (for the better).

Can anyone please help me understand why I get this inconsistency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A post with no answers that have a score of 1 or more or an accepted answer is considered "unanswered".  In other words, a zero, or negatively scored answer doesn't mean the question is "answered".
2. Closed questions are not "unanswered".
3. The data explorer isn't entirely up to date, it'll always be a bit out of date (by a matter of days, generally), so even if you fix you're query, it'll only ever be "close".

Answer (score 3):

The reasons given by Servy are valid, but they can't explain the disparity between **651,080** and **56,873**.  The real reason is that the questions that **never** had an answer have 
AnswerCount set to `NULL`, not to 0. The questions with `AnswerCount = 0` are those that **had** an answer once, but not anymore (any answer[s] have been deleted). To pick both kinds, you can use `ISNULL`:

> WHERE  ISNULL(AnswerCount,0) = 0

As a side effect, you now know how to locate questions with deleted answers (even though you can't see those deleted answers).